# curl (35) The security card or token does not exist

Tags: curl, ssl, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

After the bleeding heart openssl patch was released, I began having problems using curl to get secure files via https.  The message reads.

```
url: (35) The security card or token does not exist, needs to be initialized, or has been removed.
```

I tried using -k for insecure but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using the -ssl3 flag within curl.

```
curl -ssl3 https://someserver.com/somefile
```

I'm not sure why using ssl3 solves the issue but it does on AWS linux at least.